# How to group all `cscope` related configuration into `augroup`, so it's only applied for C/C++ files?

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd, normal-mode

How can I group all `cscope` (`:cs`) related configuration into e.g. `autocmd`, so that this configuration is only applied to `c` or `cpp` files?

I have been looking at e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133341/can-you-have-file-type-specific-key-bindings-in-vim), but it only address a single filetype, and it only applies `autocmd` to mappings (not `:set` or `:if` statements):

```
augroup pscbindings
  autocmd! pscbindings
  autocmd Filetype purescript nmap <buffer> <silent> K :Ptype<CR>
  autocmd Filetype purescript nmap <buffer> <silent> <leader>pr :Prebuild!<CR>
augroup end
```

**`cscope`** configuration in `~/.vimrc`:

```
if has("cscope")
   set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
   set csto=0
   set nocst
   set nocsverb
   " add any database in current directory
   if filereadable("cscope.out")
         cs add cscope.out
   " add database pointed to by environment
   elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
         cs add $CSCOPE_DB
   endif
   set csverb

   noremap <C-[> :cstag <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>

   nnoremap <C-_>s :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap g<C-]> :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>g :cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>c :cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap g<C-\> :cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>t :cs find t <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>e :cs find e <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>f :cs find f <C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>i :cs find i ^<C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR>$<CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>d :cs find d <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
   nnoremap <C-_>a :cs find a <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you linked is the right direction: ftplugins are made exactly for this purpose, check the doc: ([`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin))

If you have things that you want used in both `c` and `cpp` ftplugins you could put it in a function in `~/.vim/autoload/cscope.vim` and then in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` and `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` you can simply call this function.

There are a few things you'll need to pay attention to:

- You probably want your mappings to be buffer local, so you'll want to use [`:h :map-<buffer>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3cbuffer%3e)
- The options that you `set` are all global so either you want to keep them on your vimrc or you have different settings for them in different filetype and then you'll need to create buffer-local autocommands [`:h autocmd-buflocal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-buflocal) to change the values when you navigate between buffers.

I think that this article [From .vimrc to .vim](https://vimways.org/2018/from-vimrc-to-vim/) has some useful information too.

Comment: Thank you. How can an `autocmd` span multiple lines like in if-then-else statement? Do I need to use `|` to separate the differents parts (e.g. `if`, `endif`, etc.)?

Comment: I think a good rule of thumb is that when your autocmd needs to be multiline it's better to put its action in a function and to call the function in the autocmd. But if you really need to have multiline you can put a `\` at the beginning of the second line like in most vimscript scripts.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example? Although, your explanation provides all the essentials (I guess), it requires more knowledge of `vim` than I currently have.